# wsdl with no serialization info

Tags: wcf, soap, wsdl

I am trying to send a request to a web service. The wsdl can be seen here

https://amsel.dpwn.net/abholportal/gw/lp/schema/1.0/var3ws.wsdl

Creating a request is straight forward

```
            BookLabelRequest request = new BookLabelRequest();

        RpPartnerType rpt = new RpPartnerTypeClient();
        dhlService.BookLabelResponse response = rpt.BookLabel(new dhlService.BookLabelRequest());
```

but how do i pass the required parameters to it when there is no serializable BookLabelRequest exposed? and how do i pass the username/password in the header?

Sample SOAP request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:var="https://amsel.dpwn.net/abholportal/gw/lp/schema/1.0/var3bl">
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <var:BookLabelRequest portalId ="OnlineRetoure" deliveryName="Deutschland_Var3" 
                            shipmentReference="notreturnedonlabel" customerReference="CustomerRef1234567890" 
                            labelFormat="PDF" senderName1="Markus" senderName2="Beck" 
                            senderCareOfName="actualnotinuse" senderContactPhone="" 
                            senderStreet="Buschmühlenstraße" senderStreetNumber="40" 
                            senderBoxNumber="" senderPostalCode="58093" senderCity="Hagen"/>
</soapenv:Body>
```

---

The wsdl file isn't mine so i can't edit it. Is there any other way to import this. I tried to create a data contract from the xsd using svcutil but i got the error message:

The input read from "https://amsel.dpwn.net/abholportal/gw/lp/schema/1.0/
var3bl.xsd" is inconsistent with other options

I tried passing the username and password to the proxy as well

```
            RpPartnerType test = new RpPartnerTypeClient();
        ((RpPartnerTypeClient)test).ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
        ((RpPartnerTypeClient)test).ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";

        dhlService.BookLabelResponse response = test.BookLabel(new dhlService.BookLabelRequest());
```

but got the error: Authentication failed: No username given

The binding security is:

```
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a HttpWebRequest according to Mike Hadlow's blog and sent that.

http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2006/05/making-raw-web-service-calls-with.html

May be better ways to achieve this but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your WSDL is importing XSD with serialization info from other path:

```
https://amsel.dpwn.net/abholportal/gw/lp/schema/1.0/var3bl.xsd
```

but location in WSDL should specify full this path.

If you need to use UserNameToken profile you must first specify binding for your your client:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="secured">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

And use this binding in your client endpoint:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="..." name="..." contract="..." binding="basicHttpBining" 
            bindingConfiguration="secured" />
</client>
```

Once you have your client configured you need to create proxy of the service ans set credentials"

```
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = ...;
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = ...;
```